# Character is corrupted when use request.getParameter() in java

Tags: java, servlets, utf-8

I have a web page where I do a search based on the text given in a text box. This text can be in any language like japanese, chinese etc (or any mbcs character).

Now when i enter a text in japanese (or any other mbcs character), the result populates the screen (form) with some wierd characters.

For Example: `testテスト` will turn into `testãã¹ã`.

When i see the post parameters in Firebug (debugging tool) i can see that the search string goes as `testテスト` however when i put debug statements in my code, i can see that `request.getParameter("searchString")` is not able to identify the japanese characters and turn them into some wierd chars.

My JSP header already has `<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"`

I have also tried putting `pageEncoding="UTF-8"` in this but it didn't help.

I tried setting character encoding like `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")` also just before doing `request.getParameter` but that too didn't work for me.

After going through a few forums and blogs i also tried setting `useBodyEncodingForURI=true` in the `<Connector>` of tomcat config but that also did not help me.

Can anybody suggest me something to resolve this issue?

Comment: "when i put debug statements in my code" - meaning what?  What sort of debugging?  `System.out.println()`?  Which operating system?

Comment: If I'm not wrong you may need to convert it to ascii.

Comment: Hey Skaffman..by debug statements i mean some loggers in my code and not SOP statements

Answer (score 1):

set the following encoding in every servlet/ action

```
 response.setContentType("UTF-8");
 response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
 request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

also set following in first servlet/action

for japanese

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
session.setAttribute(Globals.LOCALE_KEY, new Locale("jp", "ja_JP"));
```

Comment: Hi Mohit, Thanks for your reply but this too didn't help. :( Moreover I'm returning the response back but doing a forward to a jsp depending upon success & failure (Struts framework). And as i mentioned in my post my JSp already has the charset defined as UTF-8: "<%@page contentType='text/html;charset=UTF-8' pageEncoding='UTF-8' language='java'%>"

Comment: but you need set your response encoding.
i used it and run successfully

Comment: @Mohit: Hi Mohit, I'd tried that also but that didn't work out.